# Save 2 related models through a single form

Tags: python, django

Here are two models - Property and Developer:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Apartment')
    specifications = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Basic')
    built_up_area = models.FloatField(max_length=6, null=False)
    total_area = models.FloatField(null=False)
    number_of_bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_parking_spaces = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0)
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    developer = models.ForeignKey('Developer')

    connectivity = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    neighborhood_quality = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.property_type


class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is its corresponding form:

```
class PropertyForm(ModelForm):
    developer = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
            'built_up_area',
            'total_area',
            'number_of_bedrooms',
            'number_of_bathrooms',
            'number_of_parking_spaces',
            'address_line_one',
            'address_line_two',
            'city',
            'state',
            'pin_code',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'number_of_bedrooms': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'number_of_bathrooms': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'number_of_parking_spaces': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'developer': forms.TextInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['address_line_two'].required = False,
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            AppendedText('built_up_area', 'sq ft'),
            AppendedText('total_area', 'sq ft'),
            'number_of_bedrooms',
            'number_of_bathrooms',
            'number_of_parking_spaces',
            'address_line_one',
            'address_line_two',
            'city',
            'state',
            'pin_code',
            'developer',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('Submit', 'submit', css_class='btn-block')
            )
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        developer = self.cleaned_data['developer']
        developer, created = Developer.objects.get_or_create(name=developer)
        self.instance.developer = developer

        return super(PropertyForm, self).save()
```

What could be a better way to save related objects using a single form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have this implemented, by overriding the `save` method to save the related models, is correct and is how it should be implemented. Unless you implement this logic outside of the form, in which case you are probably violating some DRY principles, the form is the correct place to manage data for multiple models.